# How to insert a newline inside a code snippet in the Swift REPL

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop

I want to prepend a line to a snippet already entered in the REPL. The screenshot shows the cursor at the point that the `newline` should be inserted.

[image]

I do not know how to do this since hitting `return` will try to *execute* the snippet.  I also tried `CMD-Ret`  and `Alt-Ret`: same behavior.  Is there any way to do this without retyping the entire snippet?

Comment: Try Control-V, Control-J

Comment: @MartinR  v nice!  where did you learn that one (I'd like to see what other goodies are there) . Pls make an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control-V, Control-J does does the trick, similarly as in an interactive terminal. [Control-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-V) means "the next character should be treated literally" and [Control-J](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/09/28/control-characters/) generates a newline character.

Comment: That's a great answer: it is well more generally useful than what I was asking!  One sometimes proves theorems more general than the specific condition.